Multiple instances for if() statements inside arrayformula()
I'm trying to create a formula in Google Sheets that evaluates each row in a sheet based on the rules I have in another sheet. Each row in the rules sheet should be treated as a rule. However, my current formula only returns the first instance that meets the criteria of a rule, instead of all instances that match the criteria. I have tried various approaches but have not made progress.
Each rule has several conditions, and if all conditions for a rule are met, the corresponding value from rules!G3:G should be returned.
'rules' sheet:



Rule ID
Account Condition
Description Contains
Category Condition
Min Amount
Max Amount
Result




2
Account1
Any
Any
Any
Any
Test1


1
Any
Rent
Any
500
2200
Rent


3
Account2
Entertainment
Any
Any
Any
Test2


4
Account2
Utilities
Any
Any
Any
Test3



Main sheet:



UniqueID
Date
Account
Description
Category
Amount
AccountKey




ID1
1/1/2024
Account1
Rent Payment
Rent
-1500
Account1


ID2
1/2/2024
Account2
Other Payment
Other
-100
Account2


ID3
1/3/2024
Account1
Another Payment
Another Category
-200
Account1


ID4
1/4/2024
Account2
Different Payment
Different Category
-300
Account2


ID5
1/5/2024
Account2
Entertainment Services
Yet Another Category
-400
Account2


ID6
1/5/2024
Account2
City Utilities
Yet Another Category
-401
Account2



Here is the desired output:



Result




Rent


Test2


Test1


Test2


Test2



Bonus, I would love to expand this formula to be able to search for a word contained in the description column of the rules sheet instead of needing to match the whole description.

part: (rules!B3:B = "Any") makes no sense

What I want that part to do is that if there is a wildcard in a given cell of the rules tab (I chose "Any" for the wildcard, but it could be anything), that is just marks that particular condition as true no matter what

would be helpful if you could extend your example data and include desired result. the arrayformula you are using is completely wrong (its just luck due to small sample that it outputs what you expect it). the first argument of IF statement needs to be boolean of size 1x1 for a given row. it cant be array of booleans for a given row. (rules!B3:B = "Any") is exactly that - array of booleans for given row.

next there is issue with * + there is certain hierarchy in place that needs to be followed. * takes always priority so + needs to be always enclosed first because (A1=1)+(A1=0)(A1=2) is (A1=1)+((A1=0)(A1=2)) and result is different from ((A1=1)+(A1=0))*(A1=2) - that is used in 99% cases so please review your data sample and carefully think trough what exactly is your desired result and logic behind it

@player0 thank you! I modified the example and removed my original formula that did not work

try:
=INDEX(IFNA(IF(REGEXMATCH(D3:D, "(?i)"&rules!C3)*(-F3:F>rules!E3)*(-F3:F<rules!F3), 
 rules!G3, VLOOKUP(C3:C, rules!B3:G, 6, 0))))



update
as already mentioned, your table with rules is insufficient so result will be:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(IF(REGEXMATCH(D9:D14&E9:E14, "Rent")*
 (-F9:F14>=VLOOKUP("Rent", C2:G5, 3, 0))*
 (-F9:F14< VLOOKUP("Rent", C2:G5, 4, 0)), VLOOKUP("Rent", C2:G5, 5, 0), VLOOKUP(C9:C14&
 IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(D9:D14, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, FILTER(C2:C5, C2:C5<>"Any"))))&
 IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(E9:E14, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, FILTER(D2:D5, D2:D5<>"Any")))), 
 {B2:B5&SUBSTITUTE(C2:C5, "Any", )&SUBSTITUTE(D2:D5, "Any", ), G2:G5}, 2, 0)), "rule not defined"))



Thank you! This is a promising start and spits out the desired result for this single example, but there are a few issues. The first is that with TRUE resulting in rules!G3, H3 always results in the value of cell rules!G3 even when incorrect. Second, because of the VLOOKUP() for FALSE, those results are just spitting out the result for the first time an account is used, so does not work when I have accounts where different rules apply to them. The third is that it would be nice if it could deal with cases where "Any" is provided as a wildcard in the rules tab like in the example.

I added an alternative example to test these kinds of issues
